# Validating Request Video File (Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel

Question: I have problem when i upload video in a correct format.
the error says that. **The Content assets failed to upload.**

The File Name that i upload is
**history_legend.mp4**

which the format of the video is correct.

I try already customize my php.ini
the max_upload_size to 500M

but still it gives me error failed to upload

**In Controller:**

```
public function content_inserting_home(Request $request)
{

    $content_bothimagevideo = $request->input('content_assets');
    $file_upload = $request->file('content_assets');

     $validatedData = $request->validate([
    'content_assets' => 'required|mimes:mp4,x-flv,x-mpegURL,MP2T,3gpp,quicktime,x-msvideo,x-ms-wmv',

    ]);


}
```

**In Blade:**

```
<form action="/previllage/content_inserting_home" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
         {{csrf_field()}}
        <div class="collection">
            <a href="#!" class="collection-item active " style="border-left:5px solid black;">Home</a>
            <a href="#!" class="collection-item" style="cursor: default;">
                <div class="row">

                    <div class="input-field col s12 m4 l4">
                        <select name="content_page">
                          <option value="" disabled selected>Select the page where you publish</option>
                          <option value="Home">Home</option>
                        </select>
                        <label>Choose the page</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-field col s12 m4 l4">
                        <select name="content_section">
                          <option value="" disabled selected>Select section where you put it in</option>
                          <option value="Sec1">Section 1</option>
                          <option value="Sec2">Section 2</option>
                          <option value="Sec3">Section 3</option>
                          <option value="Sec4">Section 4</option>
                          <option value="Sec5">Section 5</option>
                        </select>
                        <label>Choose the page</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-field col s12 m4 l4">

                      <input placeholder="Title" name="content_header" id="title" type="text" class="validate">
                      <label for="first_name">Header</label>

                    </div>


                    <br>

                </div>      
            </a>
                <div class="row">
                    <a href="#!" class="collection-item" style="cursor: default;">
                        **<div class="file-field input-field col s12 m10 l10">
                          <div class="btn">
                            <span>File</span>
                            <input type="file"  name="content_assets"  >
                          </div>
                          <div class="file-path-wrapper">
                            <input class="file-path validate" name="content_assets" placeholder="Upload Here the video & Image" type="text">
                          </div>
                           @if ($errors->has('content_assets'))
                          <span class="help-block">
                                  <strong style="color:red;">{{ $errors->first('content_assets') }}</strong>
                              </span>
                          @endif**

                        </div>
                        <img id="image-viewer" src="http://placehold.it/150" alt="your image" />
                    </a>
                </div>
                         {{-- <img id="image-viewer" src="http://placehold.it/250" alt="your image" /> --}}



            <a href="#!" class="collection-item" style="cursor: default;">
                <div class="input-field col s12 m6 l6">
                   <textarea  name="content_article" id="test"  maxlength="6000" required style="resize:none; position: relative; top:5px; border-top:0px; border-left:0px; border-right:0px;"></textarea>
                   <label>Article</label>
                </div>

            </a>

        </div>
         <button class="btn waves-effect btn-large waves-light red darken-4 right" type="submit">Publish & Save
            <i class="material-icons right">send</i>
         </button>
    </form>
```

Comment: You may need to increase the `max_post_size` (IIRC that is what is called) too.

Comment: Does it specify are proper error?

Comment: You realise that you aren't actually storing the file anywhere, right?

Comment: @Script47 i already update my to post_max_size=500M

Comment: @Script47 yes script.

Comment: @Script47 I fix already.. btw thanks for your suggestion.. I just restart all my cmd and my xampp

Comment: Don't name both of the fields `content_assets`, this is your failure.